# Indirect complement or extraposed subject?

Tags: complements

Is the content clause ('that she saw him commit the crime') in the following sentence an [extraposed subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition) or an indirect complement* licensed by 'so'?

> It just so happens that she saw him commit the crime.

*See, for example, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, p. 443.

Comment: The Wikipedia entry, to which you have helpfully provided a link, gives,early on, some useful examples.  I am sure you have looked at them, but have another look.  Could you say what the non-extraposed version would be?

Answer (score 4):

> *It just (so) happens* [*that she saw him commit the crime*].

It can't be extraposition since the content clause cannot occupy the subject position: we can't say *"That she saw him commit the crime just so happens".

And I wouldn't say that the content clause is an indirect complement licensed by "so". "So" is optional here; dropping it would not result in a loss of grammaticality or a real change of meaning.

Rather, the content clause seems to be a straightforward complement of "happens", the item that licenses it.

Comment: But if the content clause is not extraposed, then what, exactly, is the function of 'it'? Surely it cannot be the subject of an it-cleft (as, 'It was John who committed the crimes'), since such constructions obligatorily need a 'be' within them, right?

Comment: @Erick "It" is the subject. It's semantically empty, so that the content clause represents the sole argument of the matrix clause.

Comment: _It just so happens that_ is a fixed phrase, hallowed by decades of stage and radio usage. It's got a complicated syntax, all of which is completely frozen (well, you can change the tense to _happened_, but that's all). It's a pause to build drama when telling a story, before a climactic ending involving coincidence.

Comment: It's not completely fixed. For example the "so" is optional. I don't see anything complicated about the content clause being analysed as complement of "happens", which is what the OP asked about.